# Session Management с проверкой токена

Tags: android, auth, token

Мне нужно реализовать `Session Management` с токеном (токен генерируется на сервере, время жизни 2 недели). Авторизироваться можно ещё из веб-версии и токен по юзеру заменится на сервере. Сейчас я сделал `Session Management` с использованием `SharedPreferences`.

Для запросов на сервер использую `Retrofit`.

Если токен не валидный, то сервер возвращает 401ю ошибку при запросе к нему.

Единственная мысль по поводу токена - это отправлять запрос на сервер при проверке залогинен или нет юзер (это с `SharedPreferences`) и потом в зависимости от кода ответа перенаправлять на активности.

В правильном ли направлении я думаю или есть лучший/более практичный способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно это делается так.

- выбираем место где храним токен. Где угодно, главное безопасно, т.е. шифруем.
- при старте приложения смотрим есть ли токен

  - если есть, используем его
  - если нет, отправляем пользователя его получать (Login)
- если при любом из запросов на сервер получаем 401, удаляем токен и отправляем пользователя его снова получать (Login)
- если пользователь делает Logout, удаляем токен и заканчиваем приложение

Как-то так в двух словах.